# Nao Robot and "FaceDetected" variable

Tags: c++, image-processing, nao-robot

I am trying to do some visual debugging of the Nao's face detection, just draw a rectangle around the detected(s) face(s). Instead of acquire the image and use an opencv algorithm to do the face detection, I am acquiring the image (for visual debugging) and using the parameters returned by Nao's face detection system.

This system is provided by [Oki](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/naoqi/vision/alfacedetection.html#how-it-works) and all the information is available into the variable "[FaceDetected](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/naoqi/vision/alfacedetection.html#facedetected-almemory-key)". I have not problem to access to this variable. For my porpoise it is supposed I have to use "**ShapeInfo**" information.

My questions is: How can I manipulate them to get the face position into the Cartesian image space?

Note 1: I suppose the units are radians, but I have not official confirmation

Note 2: After some experiments, I have discovered that **alpha** and **beta** are relatives to the image centre and **sizeX** and **sizeY** increases/decreases in relation with the face size (as is expected). So, I suppose the information is given as an Orthographic projection

Note 3: Some examples of **alpha**, **beta** (range [-0.5,0.5]), **sizeX**, **sizeY** (range [0,1]) for a face located into the area top-right of the camera:

```
-0.232393 -0.0899552 0.358549 0.37366 
-0.232393 -0.0899552 0.358549 0.37366
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tests I have finally discovered the meaning of the FaceDetected variable. I've written a explanation [here](http://abitworld.com/nao-robot-visual-debugging-of-the-vision-variables/)

I hope it could be useful to others